# Using GDI+ in C - gdiPlusStartup function returning 2

Tags: c, gdi+

I am attempting to use GDI+ in my C application to take a screenshot and save it as JPEG. I am using GDI+ to convert the BMP to JPEG but apparently when calling the GdiplusStartup function, the return code is 2(invalid parameter) instead of 0:

```
int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    //if(GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL) != 0)
    //    printf("GDI NOT WORKING\n");
    printf("%d",GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL));
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); // get the desktop device context
    HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // create a device context to use yourself
    // get the height and width of the screen
    int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

    // create a bitmap
    HBITMAP hbDesktop = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, width, height);

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    SelectObject(hDest, hbDesktop);

    // copy from the desktop device context to the bitmap device context
    // call this once per 'frame'
    BitBlt(hDest, 0,0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // after the recording is done, release the desktop context you got..
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

    // ..and delete the context you created
    DeleteDC(hDest);
    SaveJpeg(hbDesktop,"a.jpeg",100);
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to figure out why the GdiplusStartup function is not working.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `gdiplusStartupInput` variable with the following values: `GdiplusVersion = 1, DebugEventCallback = NULL, SuppressBackgroundThread = FALSE, SuppressExternalCodecs = FALSE`

According to MSDN article `GdiplusStartup function` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

`GdiplusStartupInput` structure has default constructor which initializes the structure with these values. Since you call the function from C, constructor is not working and structure remains uninitialized. Provide your own initialization code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// As Global
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;     

// In top of main
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
GdiplusStartup(&programInfo.gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

works for me.